# python multiprocessing Pipe/Queue not terminating

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pipe

I have two questions related to pipe/queue in python.

1) Pipe is not terminating (i.e. EOFError is never thrown). I know the solution of this problem is to pass in_p to the process() function as well and close it in that function. But I don't know why that is necessary.

```
import multiprocessing

def process(out_p):
    # in_p.close()
    while True:
        try:
            value = out_p.recv()
            print value
        except EOFError:
            print 'EOFError in pipe!'
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    out_p, in_p = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(out_p,))
    proc.start()
    out_p.close()
    for i in range(10):
        in_p.send(i)

    in_p.close()
```

2) The second scenario is more complicated. On top of the pipe in the first problem. The value received from pipe is further put into a SimpleQueue. In this case, even if I pass both in_p and out_p to the process() function, it still won't terminate.

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.queues

def process(out_p, in_p, queue):
    in_p.close()
    while True:
        try:
            value = out_p.recv()
            print value
            queue.put(value**2)
        except EOFError:
            print 'EOFError in pipe!'
            queue.put('stop')
            break
def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        value = queue.get()
        print value
        if value == 'stop':
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    out_p, in_p = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    queue = multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(out_p, in_p, queue))
    proc.start()

    cons = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,))
    cons.start()

    out_p.close()
    for i in range(10):
        in_p.send(i)
    in_p.close()
    proc.join()
```

I'll be very grateful for any help!

Comment: FYI, your first example runs fine for me under Python 3.3.2.  And so does your second example.

Comment: Hmm, i was using python 2.7.5. It seems to be bug in python then.

Comment: Hmm!  Both your examples worked fine for me under 2.7.5 too.  But I'm currently running on Windows.  If you're running on a Linux-y system, it's possible that the `fork()`-based implementation there is getting lost.